# What does Toph's wanted poster say?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, translation

An [answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143814/31178) brought up this wanted posted from *The Last Airbender* season 3:

[image: enter link description here]

What's the English translation, if any?

Comment: Toph shows a nice smile at this pic. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The translated text results in this:

> Wanted
>
> Authorities are offering a reward of 1000 gold coins
>
> for the arrest of this twelve year old girl. She disguises
>
> herself as blind, and even though she is small,
>
> she is very dangerous. Information (that will lead to
>
> her arrest) will be rewarded.

[Source](https://www.etsy.com/listing/186938900/avatar-the-last-airbender-toph-wanted)

The original text:

> 緝拿逃犯
>
> 當局懸賞一千金幣
>
> 緝捕十二歲女童她
>
> 喬裝盲人個子雖小
>
> 極之危險報訊即賞

thrown into Google translate gives this (very crude) translation:

> Fugitive
>
> The authorities offered a reward of one thousand gold coins
>
> Arresting a 12-year-old girl
>
> The disguise of a blind man is small
>
> Extremely dangerous news that reward

which has the same intention.

Comment: Toph is a blind man with a small disguise? That sounds unpleasant.

Comment: I would not have expected an answer to come from Etsy. TYVM!